# Onclicklistener for a child view inside a ListView item only fired second time after onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

This is the situation: I have a Listview with some items. Inside each item there are two clickable views that are only shown after user clickes in their parent item.

It works like this:

```
productList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {

                TextView txtAdd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_add_units);
                txtAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ...
                    }
                });

                TextView txtRemove = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_remove_units);
                txtRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ...
                    }
                });

                basketProductsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
```

The first time a listview item is clicked, its txtAdd and txtRemove child views are shown and then if user clicks them, code inside their onclickListener is executed.

The problem appears ONLY IN THE FIRST listview item. First time it is clicked txtAdd and txtRemove are shown, BUT THE FIRST TIME user clicks over the child views, their parent's ItemClickListener is fired again, and then the child views (txtAdd and txtRemove) are not receiving the clickListener. Following times they are work perfectly.The weird thing is that it only happens first time on the first item in the listView.

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a linearlayout , put your `txtAdd` and `txtRemove`  inside this linearlayout  , keep Linearlayout as `visiblity=gone` .  On list item click set visiblity of that linearlayout to `visible` progarmatically . Then trigger click events for `txtAdd` and `txtRemove`.

Comment: That's pretty the same that I'm doing, isn't it @Vikrant ? Thanks anyway

Comment: Have to added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your listview xml ?

Comment: Please post more of your code. Do you use header in your list view?

Comment: Yep, i tested every descendantFocusability mode @Vikrant it's not the problem

Comment: No, I don't use header item view in list view @Georgy if you really need more code please ask specifically. Thanks

Comment: @Hugo, Please post your xml, adapter, and activity code. I thinks you added some special handling code. There is no known android voodoo in this case....

Comment: Instead of passing nested click listener add click listener to textviews in the adapter where you are inflating their views.

Comment: @Hugo have you find any solution for your problem? Actually I am also facing the same issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your listview xml `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

The Thing is our child view may be focusable so the first click will be for the focus and after that the itemClick will work. to avoide focusable add that line in the  xml

Still if it does not work then try adding

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to the child View of the listview

Comment: Fair answer, but in this context it is not applicable, seeming that the problem lies in the fact that the question poster has nested onClickListeners.